# PHP deleting multiple items with one/multiple curl request(s)?

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I have a web service call, like so:

```
$data = array(
     "id" => 1234,
     "id" => 8348,
     "id" => 9999,
     "id" => 0473
); // example
$url = 'http://myurl'; // example
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); // data converts to json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The $data contains the id's of the items to be deleted (this is the only parameter needed). I've got it to work when I want to delete just one item (one id), but I can't find out how to make it so that this call can delete multiple items at once. Using this method, it only deletes the last one in the list, which is logical, because each newer entry overrides the previous one.

I've tried storing the id's and making a web service call for each id in the array, but that doesn't seem to work, or maybe I'm just not doing it right.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$data` array will contain one item because you use the same index **"id"** for all elements in the array.
So

```
$data = array(
     "id" => 1234,
     "id" => 8348,
     "id" => 9999,
     "id" => 0473
);
```

will be transmitted as

```
$data = array(
     "id" => 0473
);
```

Output of `json_encode($data)` is

```
{"id":473}
```

To solve the problem you could add numbers to **id** like this:

```
$data = array(
     "id1" => 1234,
     "id2" => 8348,
     "id3" => 9999,
     "id4" => 0473
);
```

or pass the **id** as a nested array which i recommended

```
$data = array(
     "id" => array(1234,8348,9999,473)
);
```

Output of `json_encode($data)` is

```
{"id":[1234,8348,9999,473]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question must be asked to the people that wrote the API. We can just guess the answer.

My guess:

```
$data = array(
     "id" => array(
        1234,
        8348,
        9999,
        0473
    )
);
```